# How to have content view in cell take up entire cell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I am attempting to create a horizontal stack view and have it take up the entire cell width. I have two vertical stack views inside this horizontal stack view. I have pinned the horizontal stack view to the leading and trailing edges of the superview as well as aligned it vertically to the containing view. It seems to look as expected when I see it in the storyboard link to picture here: [image: https://imgur.com/a/6kFbhrC]

but when I run it has this spacing on the right side [image: https://imgur.com/sCEgwG3] .

I've tried to see if I could see the width of the content view of the cell by having the background this maroon color. To me, it seems like it is the entire width of the cell so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

UPDATE: After adjusting widths to the stack view. I am not quite sure if this is a stackView issue exactly. Setting a fixed width for the stackview fixes my issue for one screen but this does not work for all screens hence the attempt to constrain it to the edges. I ended up stripping out everything out of the cell and just left the title label.
[Stripped Down Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51Dzg.png)

I centered this to the parent view but it still ignores its constraints. 
[Run Time View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUfhw.png)
I am guessing auto layout does this. Not quite sure what takes priority and is forcing it to ignore my constraints. 
I looked into the debug view hierarchy and it has a purple label on the UILabel indicating that the position is ambiguous. 
[Debug View Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ8Nj.png)
I am guessing autolayout then tries its best to fix its position. Not sure what is ambiguous here.

UPDATE 2: I dont know what was wrong with the storyboard constraints I set. I ended up removing everything from the controller and starting from scratch. After doing this it worked as expected. Sometimes starting from scratch is the best thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the width of your horizontal stack view children (Both vertical stack view). You can set the width of both vertical stack view to equal this way they will take equal space and fill the parent.

[image]

Comment: I was going under the assumption that having the horizontal stack view would give the needed constraints for the children if I set the distribution = fill equally. Giving them equal widths seems to make it better. The issue I see is when the screen size changes then I need to change the width as well. I was hoping setting the distribution attribute for the horizontal stack view to fill equally would be able to do this.

Comment: Stackview depends on its children for its height and width. So maybe you can set the width of the UILabels to equal and this should take care for all screen size. Check the screenshot above for similar example.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. I may have found out that it is not a stack view issue. I have this similar issue with one label.`